# Formatting an Excel dataBase header using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table and I want to extract a portion of the columns names: for example, the column name is "Y2014", I should get the String (or integer) "2014" only
here is my code

```
Function findValue(year As String)
Dim formattedYear As String
formattedYear = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(year, 1)
findValue = formattedYear
End Function
```

I get an error of value either if I try with a simple value doing findValue("Y2014") of if I try with the cell value findValue(Q1) (where A1 content is equivalent to "Tableau1[[#En-têtes];[Y2014]])":
can someone help? thanks.

Comment: error because you should use `Right(year, 1)` instead `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(year, 1)`. However it gives you only one right character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to get rid of the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.` mention

Answer (score 0):

First impression looking at your code is that functions always return a value so you have to specify what type the function returns like

Function findValue(year As String) as string

What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: even with specifying the return type, I still get the error "#Value!" in the cell I'm supposed to get the answer